# Why doesn't this array formula work when cell reference contains a formual?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have created an array formula (first formula below) to return the nth value in Data!B:B based on the date value in B4. The formulas appear to work when I have the date in B4 but if I use the second formula below to create a date it no longer works. Can you please help to determine a way to return my desired result when maintaining a formula in B4 to return the date.

```
=VLOOKUP((SMALL(IF((Data!C:C=B4)*(Data!H:H<>"Lead"),Data!B:B),B5)),Data!B:F,5,0)

=CONCATENATE($B$2,"/",A4,"/2015")
```

Comment: The CONCATENATE function is producing a text string that probably isn't recognised as a date - what's in B2 and A4 exactly?

Comment: Standard debugging technique is to reduce the problem until it goes away. In your case, you should have reduced the problem to `IF((Data!C:C=B4),Data!B:B)`; maybe you could have figured it out from there. Also, your presentation is confusing. Are your data on multiple sheets? If not, why do some references say `Data!` and some don't? If they are on multiple sheets, reduce the problem by putting them all on one sheet and simplifying the formula. And it looks like you've got an extra (unnecessary) pair of parentheses around the `SMALL(…)` function. And why not just say that _n_ is `B5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use `DATE` function in B4, DATE takes the following arguments

`=DATE(Year,Month,Day)`

so if you have the month number in B2, and day number in A4 then you can use this formula in B4

`=DATE(2015,$B$2,A4)`

Comment: Thank you that's doing exactly what I needed. I guess I need to stop thinking "well it looks like what I want", and remember how it is being read.